# Split one row into 2 rows based on conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a requirement to split a single row into 2 rows depending on the Principal vale. If there is Principal and Interest Split into two rows if not split into one row.

The structure is like this:

| Id | Transaction Type | Principal | Interest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 83001 | Direct Debit | 100 | 2000 |
| 83002 | Direct Debit | 0 | 6000 |
| 83003 | Direct Debit | 0 | 100 |
| 83004 | Direct Debit | 90 | 40 |
| 83005 | Unpaid DD | 100 | 50 |

Among all the above rows, all the rows which have Principal  are to be split to below

```
Principal : Return Capital
Interest: Interest Repayment
```

| Id | Transaction Type | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 83001 | Return of Capital | 100 |
| 83001 | Interest Payment | 2000 |
| 83002 | Interest Payment | 0 |
| 83003 | Interest Payment | 100 |
| 83004 | Return of Capital | 90 |
| 83004 | Interest Payment | 40 |
| 83005 | Unpaid Return of Capital | 100 |
| 83005 | Unpaid Interest Payment | 50 |

Below is the SQL Script, I'm struggling to add extra row if there in any Principal payment

```sql
SELECT
    RIGHT(AgreementNumber, LEN(AgreementNumber) - 4) + ''  AS 'ID',
    TransactionTypeTable.TransTypeDescription AS ' Transaction Type',
    CASE 
       WHEN TransactionTypeTable.TransTypeDescription = 'Direct Debit' 
            AND TransNetPrincipal < 1
          THEN 'Interest Payment'
       WHEN TransactionTypeTable.TransTypeDescription = 'Cash receipt' 
            AND TransNetPrincipal < 1 
          THEN 'Interest Payment'
       WHEN TransactionTypeTable.TransTypeDescription = 'Cash receipt' 
            AND TransNetPrincipal > 1 
          THEN 'Return of Capital' 
       WHEN TransactionTypeTable.TransTypeDescription = 'Unpaid DD - No Instruction' 
            AND TransNetPrincipal < 1  
          THEN 'UnPaid Interest Paymen'
       WHEN TransactionTypeTable.TransTypeDescription = 'Unpaid DD - No Instruction' 
            AND TransNetPrincipal > 1 
          THEN 'UnPaid Return of Capital'
       WHEN TransactionTypeTable.TransTypeDescription = 'Unpaid DD - Refer To Payer' 
            AND TransNetPrincipal <1 
          THEN 'UnPaid Interest Payment'
       WHEN TransactionTypeTable.TransTypeDescription = 'Unpaid DD - Refer To Payer' 
            AND TransNetPrincipal >1 
          THEN 'UnPaid Return of Capital'
       ELSE 'Return of Capital'
    END AS 'Transaction Type',
    TransNetPrincipal AS 'Pricipal',
    TransNetInterest AS 'Interest'
FROM
    AgreementTable
INNER JOIN 
    TransactionTable ON TransactionTable.TransAgreementNumber = AgreementTable.AgreementNumber
```

Comment: Your sample data and query have nothing to do with each other.  For instance, the query references two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems an unpivot, by use of a `VALUES` table construct, and a `CASE` expression would do the trick here. Though one row won't be the same as I *assume* that 83002 shjould have the value `6000` for `amount` *not* `0`.:

```sql
SELECT YT.Id,
       CASE WHEN YT.TransactionType = 'Direct Debit' AND V.AmountType = 'Principle' THEN 'Return of Capital'
            WHEN YT.TransactionType = 'Direct Debit' AND V.AmountType = 'Interest' THEN 'Interest Payment'
            WHEN YT.TransactionType = 'Unpaid DD' AND V.AmountType = 'Principle' THEN 'Unpaid Return of Capital'
            WHEN YT.TransactionType = 'Unpaid DD' AND V.AmountType = 'Interest' THEN 'Unpaid Interest Payment'
       END AS TranasctionType,
       V.Amount
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES('Principle',YT.Principle),
                        ('Interest',YT.Interest))V(AmountType,Amount)
WHERE V.Amount != 0;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9cab545822634df61e54aa97416ef8c7)

Comment: Thanks Lamu, What V.AmountType? Which Column i'm referring this?

Comment: `V.AmountType` it's the column `AmountType` from the object aliased as `V`, @dan ... Just like `YT.Id` is the column `Id` from the object aliased as `YT`... What about `V.AmountType` confused you that `YT.Id` did not?

Comment: Also, L a r n u  please, @dan .

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Larnu, apologies for misspelling your name, Basically I'm expecting below output

Id     |Transaction Type |Amount    |
-------|---------------  |----------|
83001  |Return of Capital|100       |
83001  |Interest Payment |2000      |
83002  |Interest Payment |6000      |
83003  |Interest Payment |100       |
83004  |Return of Capital| 90       |
83004  |Interest Payment | 40       |
83005  | Unpaid Return of Capital     | 100      |
83005  | Unpaid Interest Payment    | 50    |
--------|---------------- |----------|
Using below script I'm getting below output. It's not splitting into two row one for Return Capital and other for Interest Repayment it's considering as 1 row.

**Select

RIGHT(AgreementNumber, LEN(AgreementNumber) - 4)+ ''  AS 'ID'
,TransactionTypeTable.TransTypeDescription as ' Transaction Type'
,CASE
WHEN TransactionTypeTable.TransTypeDescription = 'Direct Debit' and TransNetPrincipal <1 THEN 'Interest Payment'
WHEN TransactionTypeTable.TransTypeDescription = 'Cash receipt' and TransNetPrincipal <1
THEN 'Interest Payment'
WHEN TransactionTypeTable.TransTypeDescription = 'Cash receipt' and TransNetPrincipal >1
THEN 'Return of Capital'
WHEN TransactionTypeTable.TransTypeDescription = 'Unpaid DD - No Instruction' and TransNetPrincipal <1
THEN 'UnPaid Interest Paymen'
WHEN TransactionTypeTable.TransTypeDescription = 'Unpaid DD - No Instruction' and TransNetPrincipal >1
THEN 'UnPaid Return of Capital'
WHEN TransactionTypeTable.TransTypeDescription = 'Unpaid DD - Refer To Payer' and TransNetPrincipal <1
THEN 'UnPaid Interest Payment'
WHEN TransactionTypeTable.TransTypeDescription = 'Unpaid DD - Refer To Payer' and TransNetPrincipal >1
THEN 'UnPaid Return of Capital'
else 'Return of Capital'
END as 'Transaction Type'
,TransNetPrincipal as 'Pricipal'
,TransNetInterest as 'Interest'

From AgreementTable
inner join TransactionTable on TransactionTable.TransAgreementNumber = AgreementTable.AgreementNumber**

| Id | Transaction Type | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 83001 | Return of Capital | 3000 |
| 83002 | Interest Payment | 6000 |
| 83003 | Interest Payment | 100 |
| 83004 | Return of Capital | 130 |
| 83005 | Unpaid Return of Capital | 150 |
| -------- | ---------------- | ---------- |